# Linking glut to Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glut

I want to have an OpenGL window compared with Qt.
But, how do I link the glut/openGL libraries to Qt?
I tried some tutorials but they didn't help.

These are my problems:

1. Do I have to put the libraries to a compiler-folder in Qt?
2. Which Qt project do I have to use to start an OpenGL program?

Comment: On which operating system do you develop?

Comment: You seem to be mixing some things. So let's clarify. Are you actually referring to Qt (i.e. QtOpenGL and the like) or Qt Creator, the IDE?

Comment: sorry, windows and qt creator

Comment: How do you want to "compare" an OpenGL window with Qt? Or did you mean "compiled"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I link the glut/openGL libraries to Qt?

GLUT is not part of OpenGL. GLUT is a simple application framework to make simple OpenGL demo application. Think of GLUT as kind of a very small, very limited Qt.

Qt itself comes with acceptable OpenGL support (it's not ideal, only recently I was hampered by some of its shortcommings, but the average user won't notice it). Qt has the QGLWidget, which created a OpenGL context for you.

Linking happens as usual.

> Do I have to put the libraries to a compiler-folder in Qt?

No! Never copy libraries around. OpenGL development files come with your compiler and they are directly accessible to it. Just link with `opengl32.lib` (Windows) or `libGL.so` (Unix/Linux) or the `OpenGL` framework (on MacOS X).

> Which Qt project do I have to use to start an OpenGL program?

Whatever you like. It should of course open some window, into which you can add a QGLWidget child window.